# Drawback of the package `functional`?

Tags: packages, programming, functional

Is there some drawbacks to use the package [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional)?

This package exposes an API to code like with a standard programming code like Lua.

This implies the management, if expected, of "expansion" easily. This means that some macros can be evaluated wholly to use their "value".

Is there someone who has played with this package and met some drawbacks?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What do you want to do? Can you link to the package? Do you have any problems yourself with it? ... As the question is now, one could just answer "Maybe", to follow the style of the question.

Comment: Some clarifications added...

Comment: I suspect this falls under the "opinion based" close reason. the package basically provides an alternative (not expandable) interface to expl3, it has advantages and disadvantages but not sure the question in this form fits the site format

Comment: For one, it definitely has some overhead (i.e. slower) by "simulating" the code (actually I'd rather something that can "compile" to TeX code, that way you get the ease of programming but not the overhead). // (in any case if you want to store nontrivial things into macros you still need to learn how expansion works)

Comment: Side note, obviously everything you can do in (any package) you can also do in expl3, just with possibly more ugly syntax.